# Tabulator AjaxFiltering Add/Remove Filters

Tags: tabulator

I have a checkbox that on toggle sets a filter, noticed it was creating duplicates with the same name. So, I tried different combinations of these examples but every every hit they cause the table to refresh. Is there a way to let the filter work happen then let the ajaxFiltering kick in after it's complete for a single hit to the API?

```
table.clearFilter();
table.removeFilter("showSomething", "=", !this.checked);
table.addFilter("showSomething", "=", this.checked);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use **setFilter** `table.setFilter("showclosed", "=", this.checked);`, for some reason it was just not clear in the documentation that it was available. Went from Adding to Removing but nothing about editing an existing. Once you dig a bit deeper you see examples being used and can put 2-2 together.